# Why can't Cu + HCl -> CuCl2 + H2 happen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

1)How can I tell if a reaction like Zn + Hcl -> ZnCl2 + H2 can happen or not?

2)How can I tell if a reaction forms a precipitate and how do I know where the arrow goes? Like 2 AgNO3 + K2CrO4 -> Ag2CrO4 (precipitate) + 2 KNO3

I might come back with some new questions, but for now, thanks.

Comment: Depends on the conditions like temperature, pressure, catalyst (for the speed of reaction) etc.

Comment: Yeah but I have an exercise in my book where it literally says: Which one of these simple(? i am translating) reactions don't happen?

Comment: Then you infer your answer from: (1) electrochemical series; (2) solubility table.

Comment: Can you explain me how to use the electrochemical series table?

Comment: Why, sure, it's very simple. Metals more active than H will react with HCl, and the rest won't.

Comment: This might prove useful https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/redoxeqia/ecs.html

Comment: @IvanNeretin so what you are saying is that if on the table, the element is below the "H", it can't form a reaction, right?

Comment: I deliberately avoided the terms like "above" and "below", because sometimes the series is shown upside down, or left to right, or right to left. Other than that, yes.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Can you also help me with the usage of the solubility table? To be a precipitate it has to be insolubile, right? So I see an example here on my book: AgNO3 + K2CrO4 -> Ag2CrO4 (precipitate) + 2 KNO3. Obviously I go on the solubilty chart and check if Ag and CrO are insoluble, and if they are I put an arrow. But what about this: HCl + NaOH -> NaCl + H2O. Shouldn't I put an arrow on NaCl since it's insoluble? Also what's the difference between a precipitate and neutralization, since the last example I made is from the part "neutralization" of my book.

Comment: That's generally right, you put a down arrow next to a compound which is insoluble. As to whether NaCl is soluble $\scriptsize\text{(hint: it is)}$, you may check that in the same solubility table. As for neutralization, well, that's a different kind of reaction, and you should expect it when you have an acid against a base, no matter what's the solubility.

Comment: @IvanNeretin@Natasha Thanks for the help, I really needed it